# Class Design Inheritance/Composition

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have to produce a class diagram for a condition, condition was something like:

> Fruits have colors and fruits can grow. Apples are fruits.
>       They have seeds. Seeds can make new apples.

I would like to have some experts advice before I implement any design.

I was thinking some thing like this but I am no expert so please help me out here

```
abstract class Fruit
{
    protected $_color;

    abstract function grow();

    protected function seed(Fruit $fruit)
    {
        return $fruit;
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit
{

}
```

How can this be achieved using composition or inheritance ?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: its not a homework but it was given to me as a test job by my mentor at work

Comment: If it suits better I shall tag it as homework :) (but it's not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fruits that have seeds. Apple is one of those fruits. So I would use a simple plain inheritance design:

```
abstract class Fruit
{
     private $color;

     public function getColor(){/* */};
     public function setColor($color){/* */}

     abstract public function grow();
}

abstract class SeedableFruit extends Fruit
{
    public function seed()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

class Apple extends SeedableFruit
{
    public function grow()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

In this way you cannot reuse the implementation of the grow method of a non-`SeedableFruit` in a `Fruit` with seeds, but if you think how natural evolution works, it makes sense... because in that case the two fruits have a common ancestor that grows in the same way, so the problem could be resolved inserting that common ancestor in the class hierarchy.

The alternative design was to use a [DecoratorPattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to describe a fruit that can have seeds, and then create an Apple with seeds with a call like `new SeedableFruitDecorator(new Apple());`. But I think it's not the correct way, since **an Apple has always seeds**.

Answer (score 0):

If I'll try to create an object for that I'll come up with this one:

```
abstract class Fruit{
protected $color;
protected $age;
public $isSeedless;

public function getColor(){
return $this->color;
}

public function getAge(){
return $this->age;
}

public function setColor($color){\
$this->color = $color;
}

public function setAge($age){
$this->age = $age;
}

abstract function getFruit();
}

class Apple extends Fruit{
protected $appleCount;

public function __construct(){
$this->isSeedless = false;
}

public function getFruit(){
$fruit = new Apple();
return $fruit;
}
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // This is what i would do: 
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace ApplesAndFruitsDesign
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<string> colors = new List<string>() { "red" };

                Fruit apple = new Fruit(colors, true, true, 3, "Apple");
                Console.Write("MyFruit Details: Fruit.Name = {0}", apple.FruitName);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Fruit
        {
            public List<string> Colors { get; set; }
            public bool CanGrow { get; set; }
            public bool HasSeeds { get; set; }
            public int SeedsCount { get; set; }
            public string FruitName { get; set; }

            public Fruit(List<string> colors, bool canGrow, bool hasSeeds, int seedsCount, string name)
            {
                this.Colors = colors;
                this.CanGrow = canGrow;
                this.HasSeeds = hasSeeds;
                this.SeedsCount = seedsCount;
                this.FruitName = name;
            }

            public List<Fruit> MakeFruitFromSeeds()
            {
                List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
                for (int i = 0; i < this.SeedsCount; i++)
                {
                    Fruit fruit = new Fruit(this.Colors, this.CanGrow, this.HasSeeds, this.SeedsCount, this.FruitName);

                    fruits.Add(fruit);
                }

                return fruits;
            }
        }
    }
```